# Connection to MYSQL with command line using the password in quotes

Tags: command-line, mysql

Im giving a command line as -p$3 which will take the password and if the password dosent have $ it is working but if the password has $ the -p$3 is not working. How can we prompt the password which has $ in it.

Comment: You need to add two double quotes before and after your password

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double quotes before and after you password

```
 my_pass="some_password"

 #or in the case you're getting the password from a command-line argument

 mypass="$1"
 mysql -u user -p"$mypass"
```

Or if you have `$$` in your password ( bash will evaluate this to its PID
number) you have to add `\` before the `$$` in your password :

```
./script.sh some_arg1 some_arg2 some_pass_\$$
```

But note that this is not secure to pass the password as a parameter in the command line in the plain text form because that line might go to your `~/.bash_history`.